# get iot device shadow from http rest

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, http, iot, shadow

Everyone!

I'm interesting to get shadows of my IOT device from HTTP rest. I've follow aws instruction
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-shadow-rest-api.html

Then I've got example code in aws to call rest request with authentication signature 4.

```
    # Copyright 2010-2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
#
# This file is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
# You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the
# License is located at
#
# http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/
#
# This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
# OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
# language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
#
# ABOUT THIS PYTHON SAMPLE: This sample is part of the AWS General Reference 
# Signing AWS API Requests top available at
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html
#

# AWS Version 4 signing example

# EC2 API (DescribeRegions)

# See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html
# This version makes a GET request and passes the signature
# in the Authorization header.
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac 
import requests # pip install requests

# ************* REQUEST VALUES *************
method = 'GET'
service = 'iot'
host = 'a1tr2o248zti42-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-2'
endpoint = 'https://a1tr2o248zti42-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/things/"my device"/shadow'
request_parameters = 'Action=DescribeRegions&Version=2013-10-15'
request_parameters = ''

# Key derivation functions. See:
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python
def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

# Read AWS access key from env. variables or configuration file. Best practice is NOT
# to embed credentials in code.
access_key = 'my key from IAM'
secret_key = 'my secret key from IAM'
if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print('No access key is available.')
    sys.exit()

# Create a date for headers and the credential string
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope


# ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

# Step 1 is to define the verb (GET, POST, etc.)--already done.

# Step 2: Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query 
# string (use '/' if no path)
canonical_uri = '/' 

# Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example (a GET request),
# request parameters are in the query string. Query string values must
# be URL-encoded (space=%20). The parameters must be sorted by name.
# For this example, the query string is pre-formatted in the request_parameters variable.
canonical_querystring = request_parameters

# Step 4: Create the canonical headers and signed headers. Header names
# must be trimmed and lowercase, and sorted in code point order from
# low to high. Note that there is a trailing \n.
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'

# Step 5: Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
# in the canonical_headers list, delimited with ";" and in alpha order.
# Note: The request can include any headers; canonical_headers and
# signed_headers lists those that you want to be included in the 
# hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'

# Step 6: Create payload hash (hash of the request body content). For GET
# requests, the payload is an empty string ("").
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(('').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# Step 7: Combine elements to create canonical request
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash


# ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
# Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use, either SHA-1 or
# SHA-256 (recommended)
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
# Create the signing key using the function defined above.
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)

# Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


# ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************
# The signing information can be either in a query string value or in 
# a header named Authorization. This code shows how to use a header.
# Create authorization header and add to request headers
authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

# The request can include any headers, but MUST include "host", "x-amz-date", 
# and (for this scenario) "Authorization". "host" and "x-amz-date" must
# be included in the canonical_headers and signed_headers, as noted
# earlier. Order here is not significant.
# Python note: The 'host' header is added automatically by the Python 'requests' library.
headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'Authorization':authorization_header}


# ************* SEND THE REQUEST *************
request_url = endpoint + '?' + canonical_querystring

print('\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Request URL = ' + request_url)
r = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers)

print('\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

I've tried with this code on Lambda and I've got same results:

START RequestId: 6ae186ca-0ebb-4ce8-be09-154dedb6b3d4 Version: $LATEST
BEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Request URL = https://a1tr2o248zti42-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/things/BibaIot1/shadow
RESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Response code: 403
{"message":"Forbidden","traceId":"3bc444f1-b186-2f0f-e72d-eeebd5f1802f"}

I've tried with postman but with the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I am also facing the same issue. I am trying with postman.